# Windows 8 metro javascript app binding to a table

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs, microsoft-metro

I am having trouble binding a table in my javascript metro app instead of binding with the html provided in the template it puts in a load of divs and renders the json as a string. This is what I have:

```
<tr id="tableRow" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <td data-win-bind="innerText: label"></td>
    <td data-win-bind="innerText: value"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>col1</th>
           <th>col2</th>
           <th>col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>     
    <tbody class="topContent" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ selectionMode: 'none' }"></tbody>
</table>
```

The javascript I am using to bind (topContent is a list of { label, value} objects:

```
function bindContent() {
    var list = new WinJS.Binding.List();

    topContent.forEach(function (item) {
        list.push(item);
    });

    var listView = document.querySelector(".topContent").winControl;
    var template = document.getElementById("tableRow");
    listView.layout = new ui.ListLayout();
    listView.itemTemplate = template;
    listView.itemDataSource = list.dataSource;
}
```

Comment: I see neither JavaScript nor JSON in the question...is that really right? (I haven't done a "JavaScript metro app" but what with the word "JavaScript" in the name...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder updated to include the js for binding. I am inclined to believe the issue is with my templates rather than the js though

Comment: Have you checked what's happening when you change your listview to a div element and change your template to use divs? I don't know exactly how the html is rendered when you build up your template and table like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use a `ListView` like this. The `ListView` control adds a whole stack of extra elements to do its work, which is causing your table problems.

The answer is to work with the `WinJS.Binding.Template` control directly and use it to insert rows into your table element. Here is the HTML you'll need for the template:

```
<table >
    <tbody id="myTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
        <tr >
            <td data-win-bind="innerText: label"></td>
            <td data-win-bind="innerText: value"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You need to put a complete table and `tbody` in the markup so that the browser doesn't get upset about finding an unattached tr element or insert the tbody element itself. The outer element of a template is discarded, so only the `tr` element will be generated from the template when you use it.

Here is the markup for the table, where the generated elements will be inserted - this is what you had, except I have added an id attribute so I can find the element to insert content into from Javascript:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>col1</th>
           <th>col2</th>
           <th>col2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>     
    <tbody id="myTableBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Finally, here is the code:

```
WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
    var tableBody = document.getElementById("myTableBody");
    var template = document.getElementById("myTemplate").winControl;

    topContent.forEach(function (item) {
        template.render(item, tableBody);
    });
});
```

You need to make sure that the `Promise` returned by `WinJS.UI.processAll` is fulfilled before you use the template. Call the `render` method for each item you want to process - the arguments are the data item to pass to the template for data binding and the DOM element to insert the generated elements into.

Comment: supected it might have been this. Tip to anyone with similar problems - if you use the dom explorer you can see the extra markup that comes with listviews

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the bindContent() function inside the processAll() promise? If not, try the following and see if it works.

```
WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
   bindContent();
};
```