# Windows Store App: Grid implementation with inline editing

Tags: grid, windows-store-apps

I am creating a Windows Store app using HTML & JS. Here I want to provide a grid like interface to user with inline editing. Is their any control which is similar to jqGrid? I tried with jqGrid but it seems that jqGrid is not compatible with Windows Store App.

What is the best way to implement it?

Comment: I didn't find any suitable answer to this question but I created a table as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094764/windows-8-metro-javascript-app-binding-to-a-table  question & rather inline edit we are opening popup box for edit. Looking for some free Grid kind of component/control. I don't know whether this is right way of implementation or not.